# Make object attributes available in 'this' scope

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to do

```
console.log(some_value);
```

instead of

```
console.log(some_object.attributes.some_value);
```

Is there a way to make that object's attributes available in the current 'scope' ('scope' isn't the word I'm looking for, but I hope you understand what I'm asking).

I'm searching somethin like the 'with' syntax in Classic ASP, where you can do

```
Dim myObject = Server.CreateObject(".......")
with myObject
  .method1()
  .property1 = "Test"
end with
```

Regards

Comment: It's bad practice to use `with` in JavaScript (it is even disabled in strict mode!). If you have to access `some_object.attributes` often, assign it to a variable. If you want a fluent interface (like `myObject.method1().property1 = "Test"` looks like) implement it!

Comment: I know, I know, it's a hacky thing, but I can't change the way half of the project is done. Also, I'll use it in places where I need to access a lot of properties, and where I'm sure it won't conflict with anything else.

Comment: It's still cleaner to assign `some_object.attributes` to a variable then. Readability is more important than avoiding typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement for that:

```
with(some_object.attributes) {
    console.log(some_value);
}
```

Comment: wau!  That was quick and easy. I never thought about searching "with" in JS. Thank you!